# I have a string value i need to check the format of the value in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a INPUT VARIABLE as string 'AB1234567' it should not be more than 9 digits. i need a function in oracle Using regular expressions i need to check the format of the string.

i.e The first two characters of the string should be alphabetes and the next 7 characters should be numbers.

If i get any other special characters in the first two characters of string the function need's to return 'F' and next 7 characters should be numbers if i  get any junk characters in the next 7 variables then it needs to return 'f'.

The universal format of the string is 'AB1234567' first two characters are alpha and the next 7 should be the numbers .

Thank you

Comment: I have no experience in Oracle plsql, but a working regular expression would be something like `^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{0,7}$`. The `a-zA-Z` part allows upper & lower case. If it needs to be upper case, then change that to `A-Z`. The `0,7` means between 0 and 7 instances. Change that to `1,7` if you need at least 1 or so.

Comment: Well thanks for yous answer but the oracle regexp syntax differs i guess.

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: Ah yes sir  i have tried something but its not working out so thought of posting it here in our forum.

Comment: @SanthoshPogaku According to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm the regular expression should be good.

Comment: @Manngo tried that too but unable to solve the puzzle sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexp_like with different character classes to check for different patterns.

```
create or replace function str_test(txt in varchar2) return varchar2 as
begin
    if not regexp_like(txt, '^[[:alpha:]]{2}') then
        return 'F';
    elsif not regexp_like(txt, '^.{2}\d{7}$') then
        return 'f';
    else
        return 'some other output';
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Can i handle both situations in a single statements ?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you need something like this:

(upss, I missed `not be more than 9 digits` part, updated)

```
create function func(var nvarchar2)
return nvarchar2
as
begin 
    if NOT REGEXP_LIKE(var, '^[A-Z]{2}') then
      return 'F';
    elsif NOT REGEXP_LIKE(var, '^..[0-9]{7}$') then
      return 'f';
    else 
      return 'ok';
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you man :) you got my point i guess i got my answer i re designed the code and using it .

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION str_test (
  str IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN CHAR
AS
BEGIN
  IF str IS NULL THEN
    RETURN 'X';
  ELSE IF LENGTH( str ) != 9 THEN
    RETURN 'Y'
  ELSE IF   SUBSTR( str, 1, 1 ) NOT BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'
         OR SUBSTR( str, 2, 1 ) NOT BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' THEN
    RETURN 'F';
  ELSE
    TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( str, 3 ) );
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN other THEN
    RETURN 'f';
END;
/
```